# WPF Datagrid - Not showing any Scrollbar

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollbar

My Datagrid has a binding on an ObservableCollection and gets filled after grouping some values fetched by EF.

My Problem is, that the datagrid-height grows beyond the window size.
Does anyone know how to get that fixed... I almost googled myself to death.. :o

```
<UserControl x:Class="UltranizerV2.Views.Storage.InventoryList"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <DockPanel  Grid.Row="0" >
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PresentableInventoryItems}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Produkttitel" Width="350" Binding="{ Binding ProductTitle}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sku" Width="100" Binding="{ Binding Sku}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Menge" Width="60"  Binding="{ Binding Quantity}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>    
            </DataGrid>
        </DockPanel>
        <Label Grid.Row="1">Arsch</Label>
        </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: What is the parent control for this `InventoryList` control? Where is it placed?

Comment: it is embedded into another usercontrol

Comment: Directly or as child of other controls? If you'll keep going up the visual tree from where `InventoryList` is placed is there `StackPanel`, `ScrollViewer`, `Canvas` or something that would give its child infinite amount of space to grow?

Comment: ok ._.  the problem was a parent stackpanel.. your comment helped me :)

Comment: write it as an answer so i can accept your solution :3

Comment: Sure. [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015890/wpf-datagrid-not-showing-any-scrollbar/24016534#24016534) added

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To sum up comments your control looks fine which would suggest that the problem is somewhere up the visual tree. Most likely `InventoryList`, or one of its parents, it's placed in control that gives its children infinite amount of space to grow like `StackPanel`, `ScrollViewer` or `Canvas`. Because of that `DataGrid` can grow to accommodate all item hence not scroll bar is visible.

Remove that control or replace it with one that limits the size of its children

Comment: if a StackPanel is found, in my case a WrapPanel was a good substitute.

Comment: Good advice. Making the parent StackPanel into a Grid solved this for me. My datagrid was then in a row where <RowDefinition Height="*" /> but a border further up restricted the height.

Comment: Is there an hint, which Controls let their Children grow indefinitely?

Comment: @MatthiasMüller there aren't that many controls that behave like that. I think I've listed them all in my answer. Apart from inspecting visual tree there is no hint

Comment: In my case my grid was in a UserControl, hosted in a ContentControl in a Grid row with Height="auto". (Should have been Height="*".)

Answer (score 7):

Set The Property in datagrid

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use the scrollviewer like

```
  <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PresentableInventoryItems}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="500">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Produkttitel" Width="350" Binding="{ Binding ProductTitle}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sku" Width="100" Binding="{ Binding Sku}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Menge" Width="60"  Binding="{ Binding Quantity}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>    
            </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

If I have define the height of Datagrid the Scrollbar visible.

[image]

Comment: I have edited my answer I have added height of Datagrid

Answer (score 6):

Here is the best answer and I will tell you why.

1. You have to use special properties of DataGrid are **ScrollViewer**

> ```
> ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
> ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
> ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
> ```

2. You have to adjust **Height** dinamically to parent of the **DataGrid**.

   Height="{Binding ElementName=parentElementName, Path=ActualHeight}"

This is working example of my code.

```
 <Grid x:Name="gridClientsContainer">
     <DataGrid  x:Name="dgClients"  IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionMode="Single"    VerticalAlignment="Top"        Margin="0 0 0 0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ClientItems}"  RowHeaderWidth="0"    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="{Binding ElementName=gridClientsContainer, Path=ActualHeight}">
       <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}" Header="Last Name" MinWidth="120" />
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="First Name" MinWidth="100" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```xml
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
<RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
```

It worked for me.